# Linux Stack - main() why ebp is not pushed onto the stack

Tags: linux, assembly, fedora

I'm viewing the stack at the beginning of main, but the ebp of main is missing.

I declared a variable to check where will it's located on the stack, it turns out that there is zeros between this variable and the return address to `n __libc_start_main` !

System I'm using

```
I'm using fedora Linux 3.1.2-1.fc16.i686 
ASLR is disabled.
Debugging with GDB.
```

Here's the code :

```
void main(){

        char ret ='a';

}
```

Register information:

```
(gdb)
eax            0x1      1
ecx            0xbffff5f4       -1073744396
edx            0xbffff584       -1073744508
ebx            0x2dbff4 2998260
esp            0xbffff554       0xbffff554
**ebp            0xbffff558       0xbffff558**
esi            0x0      0
edi            0x0      0
eip            0x804839a        0x804839a <main+6>
```

stack

```
(gdb) x/8xw $esp
0xbffff554: 0x00000000(local var) 0x00000000(missing ebp!) 0x0014d6b3(return to libc_start)      0x00000001

0xbffff564:     0xbffff5f4      0xbffff5fc      0x00131fc4      0x0000082d
```

The only thing that I can think of is that the function prologue of the `libc_start_main` is not pushing the main's ebp for some reason !

---

Edit 1:

-compiled without Opatmization just (gcc -ggdb file file.c)

Assembly of main ( gcc version 4.6.2 20111027 )

```
 push   %ebp

 mov    %esp,%ebp
 sub    $0x10,%esp
 movb   $0x61,-0x1(%ebp)
 leave
 ret
```

A break point at the local variable to view the stack shows the same thing the variable followed by zeros then the return to `libc_start`

Comment: What compiler and compiler options did you use?  (Did you use -O?)

Comment: gcc -ggdb -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -o file file.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no *requirement* for a particular calling convention to be used in the assembly code generated by a compiler. That's why it's called a *convention* rather than a requirement :-)

In any case, you need to keep in mind that the 'normal' x86 calling convention for C requires the function itself to handle set-up and tear-down of the stack frame. In other words, this is the responsibility of `main` rather than the startup code (the code that generally runs *before* your `main` to set up the C runtime environment such as stack setup, creation of `argc/argv`, any library pre-initialisation and so on).

Additionally, the `ebp` pushed on to the stack is the *previous* value of `ebp` before the current stack frame is built.

Part of that build process for the current stack frame is the saving of the current ebp and then loading a new value into the `ebp` register to easily access passed parameters and locals.

You can see that by compiling your code snippet with `gcc -S`:

```
main:
    pushl    %ebp              ; Push PREVIOUS ebp.
    movl     %esp, %ebp        ; Load ebp for variable access.
    subl     $16, %esp         ; Allocate space on stack.

    movb     $97, -1(%ebp)     ; Store 'a' into variable.

    leave                      ; Tear down frame and return.
    ret
```

The first three lines and the last two are mirror images of each other, the set-up and tear-down code. There's a good chance in this case that the startup code had `ebp` set to zero, possibly because it didn't care - it doesn't have to worry about calling conventions other than to ensure `argc` and `argv` are there.

Comment: I guess this is the only explanation. By startup you mean the libc_start_main right ?

Comment: @Hannah, it's the code that runs _before_ your main, see the update to this answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile without optimization, you'll almost certainly find that `ebp`/`rbp` is in fact pushed pushed onto the stack and then set up based on `esp`/`rsp`. It is, however, done by `main` itself and not by `libc` as you appear to suggest.

Here is the assembly code produced by `gcc 4.4.5`:

```
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movb    $97, -1(%rbp)
        leave
        ret
       .cfi_endproc
```

If you compile with optimization options, you might find that the entire body of `main` is optimized away (`gcc -O3`):

```
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        rep
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

Instead of guessing, why not look at the disassembly (e.g. in `gdb`) to see what happens in your particular case?

Also, even in the unoptimized case you have to actually execute the function prologue for the registers to be set up the way you expect.

Finally, you should not be surprised when you see apparent gaps between data on the stack, as the stack is subject to alignment:

```
   -mpreferred-stack-boundary=num
       Attempt to keep the stack boundary aligned to a 2 raised to num
       byte boundary.  If -mpreferred-stack-boundary is not specified, the
       default is 4 (16 bytes or 128 bits).
```

Comment: I disassembled it, and the main is pushing the ebp. Is there a way to set a breakpoint before main starts ? so I can examine the ebp value before main pushes it ? otherwise as paxdiablo said the ebp value zero at the start.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling for x86_64 then `ebp`/`rbp` is callee saved.  That means that `main()` should save it if it needs to use it.  If not then there is no requirement for the old register value to be saved by the either callee or the caller.

See section 3.2 of the [AMD64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) for more information if you are interested.